# Can i get steam profile url via user login?

Tags: steam

I am trying to write my own program that will search for the Steam profile by login, can I do this through the steam api or through something like that?

Comment: Did you search in Steam Documentation https://steamcommunity.com/dev ?

Comment: Yea, but i doesn't find it

Answer (score 1):

you need to use the Steam Api. Steam has its own website (https://developer.valvesoftware.com/) where you can find all the commands you need for your php script. You can do all the programming yourself or you can use one of the many ready-made scripts from Github or other websites. For my project a Github user called SmItH197 helped me and he has a script for the Steamauth and Demo. In this demo there are many lines you can use for yourself. (https://github.com/SmItH197/SteamAuthentication)

With best regards, No_One !